# Omit quotes when generating .ex file

Tags: elixir

I'm currently trying to generate the file `api.ex` from `template.exs`.
I have a function that returns a string value of `"name"` but I want it to be printed into the api.ex as only `name`

I already tried:
`String.replace(~s("name"), ~s("), "")`

The code that returns my still quoted string is: 
`<%= inspect type |> Inflex.underscore |> erase_quotes %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is of the precedence of function calls and pipes.

`inspect x |> f` is the same as `inspect(x |> f)`, not `inspect(x) |> f`.

This should work:

```
<%= inspect(type) |> Inflex.underscore |> erase_quotes %>
```

but.. the reason you're getting the double quotes in the first place is that you're using `inspect` which adds those. Removing the call to `inspect`will remove the quotes. The following should work:

```
<%= type |> Inflex.underscore %>
```